# header location url not working in ipage

Tags: php, html, sql

I have built a login page for the admin panel,after succesful login the page will redirect to the dashboard.php.When am running in localhost it is working fine,session also working.But when I uploaded in Ipage the page is not redirecting,it is simply reloading the login page.
My session code is

```
    <?php
 session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['pass']))
{
header('Location: dashboard.php');
}
?>
```

The validation code and redirecting code

```
<?php
   //session_start();

    function login($username, $password)
{


    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

   $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
   $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);

   if( $num_row == 1 )
   {
     while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($result) )
     {
      return true;//$_SESSION['userid'] = $row['userid'];
     }
   } else {
      return false;
   }

  return true;
}
    include("connect.php");

if (isset($_REQUEST['login'])){
    $validLogin = login($_REQUEST['user'], $_REQUEST['pass']);

    if ($validLogin)
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] =$_REQUEST['user'];
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $_REQUEST['pass'];
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
        echo 'hi there';
     } else 
     {
        echo "<font color='white'><h1> Incorrect Details,Entry Prohibited :) </h1></font> ";
     }

}
  ?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections; you should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: Is $validLogin true or false?

Comment: if($vaildLogin) true then the code executes

Comment: Yep I got that, but is it actually true when it's on the server? You could try adding exit($validLogin) after calling login, just to mak sure. Otherwise, are you sure that the session is started on the dashboard page? If not, it might redirect you to the login page...

Comment: ya it is true..I even removed sesssion from dashboard and login page it is still not redirecting to the other page

Comment: Well yes, if you remove the session, you'll stay on the login page

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
```

at first of line

```
if ($validLogin)
{
    $_SESSION['user'] =$_REQUEST['user'];
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $_REQUEST['pass'];
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
    exit;
 } else 
 {
    echo "<font color='white'><h1> Incorrect Details,Entry Prohibited :) </h1></font> ";
 }
```

Comment: where should i add that code..? after the session php tag or after my validation php tag..?

Comment: I have added this code:  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);     no error is showing

Answer (score 1):

You can't do an `echo` after your `header()` . Uncomment it and add an exit as shown below.

```
if ($validLogin)
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] =$_REQUEST['user'];
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $_REQUEST['pass'];
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
        //echo 'hi there'; //<------ Commented this
        exit;// <---- Added exit 
     } else 
     {
        echo "<font color='white'><h1> Incorrect Details,Entry Prohibited :) </h1></font> ";
     }
```

Comment: So it says..`Incorrect Details,Entry Prohibited` ?? Btw why have you commented `session_start();` . It should be on the top next to the `<?php` open tag.

Comment: It is at the top of the same page,the session code that I have given,so no need of again initializing it..so i commented it.

Comment: Seems like the session is not _being set_. Please [`enable the error reporting`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1003917) on your code and check [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1978702/1003917)

Comment: I have written this  error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);  no error is showing

Comment: Can you check if your session is really being set ? `<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test']="somvalue";
print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: I have removed session from this page and dashboard page and tried,it is still not redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Remove space after `Location:` and try following code

> header("Location:dashboard.php");

Comment: OP mentioned that it already worked on his localhost. Maybe this is a session issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ob_clean

```
if ($validLogin)
{
    ob_clean();// <---- Added this
    $_SESSION['user'] =$_REQUEST['user'];
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $_REQUEST['pass'];
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
    //echo 'hi there'; //<------ Commented this
    exit;// <---- Added exit 
 } else 
 {
    echo "<font color='white'><h1> Incorrect Details,Entry Prohibited :) </h1></font> ";
 }
```

Edit: according to your comments on other posts, you disabled the session.. make sure it's enabled, both on login and dashboard page